# How to make 'Shoulda' test output easier to read and in Colour!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, colors, rspec, shoulda

I currently working on a project which uses Spree Cart and which has hence forced me to switch from testing with RSpec to testing with Shoulda.

I really like the output I get from rspec and am wanting to get similarly readable output using Shoulda.

Specifically how do I achieve similar output as I would achieve with the rspec command below using shoulda?

```
$ spec spec --color --format specdoc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shoulda is a library within Test::Unit.  You can get colored Test::Unit output by installing the redgreen gem

http://github.com/mynyml/redgreen/blob/master/README

Comment: Worked like a charm! Cheers.
In short from the article one needs to:
    gem install redgreen

And add the following to test_helper.rb
    require 'redgreen'

Thanks Winfield!

Answer (score 0):

You can get human-friendly output (not as nice as RSpec's, but workable) by simply passing the `--verbose` or `-v` flag to Ruby:

```
$ ruby -v test/your_test.rb
```

If you're using `Rake::TestTask` to run your Shoulda tests, there's an environment variable for passing options:

```
$ TESTOPTS='--verbose' rake
```